# Slow MySQL query with millions of records,group by and join

Tags: mysql, performance

I have a  table that logs device data connections, the table is currently at 82 million rows. I have a nother table  which holds device information , such as location, serial number, customer etc, which has 4 thousand records.

table 1 has the following structure:

```
+---------------+-------------+
| Column        | type        | 
+---------------+-------------+
| id            | int(11)     | Primary Key
| billing_date  | date        |
| imsi          | varchar(255)| 
| bytes_input   | int(10)     | 
| bytes_output  | int(10)     | 
| total_in_kibs | int(10)     | 
+-----+---------+-------------+
```

with an index:  group_idx, which includes imsi, billing_date, total_in _kibs, bytes_input, bytes_output

table 2 has the following structure:

```
+---------------+-------------+
| Column        | type        | 
+---------------+-------------+
| id            | int(11)     | Primary Key
| System        | varchar(50) |
| Customer      | varchar(50) | 
| Sitecode      | varchar(50) | 
| Serialnumber  | varchar(50) | 
| Name          | varchar(50) | 
| imsi          | varchar(255)| 
+-----+---------+-------------+
```

with an index:  site_idx, which includes imsi, Name,System,Customer,Sitecode,Serialnumber
id is the primary key

what I want to do is find the total amount of  data , the total_in_kibs column, used by each device within a given month.

The query I am using is:

```
select x.imsi,y.name, y.Customer, y.System, y.Serialnumber, 
(x.bytesin / 1048576) as 'In (Mb)', (x.bytesout / 1048576) as 'Out (Mb)', 
(x.total / 1024) as 'Total (Mb)' 
FROM  
    (SELECT imsi, sum(bytes_input) as bytesin, 
    sum(bytes_output) as bytesout, sum(total_in_kibs) as total 
   FROM table1 
   WHERE month(billing_date) = 5 
   GROUP BY imsi) as x 
JOIN table2 as y 
on y.imsi = x.imsi
```

the explain command gives the following:

```
+---+-----------+------------+------+---------------+----------+---------+------------+-------------------------------------+
| id|select_type| table      | type | possible_keys | key      | key_len | ref        | rows     | Extra                    |
+---+-----------+------------+------+---------------+----------+---------+------------+----------+--------------------------+
| 1 | PRIMARY   | y          | index | imsi,sign_idx| sign_idx | 479     | NULL       | 4100     | Using where; Using index |
| 1 | PRIMARY   | <derived2> | ref   | key0         | key0     | 258     | data.y.imsi| 20087    |                          |
| 2 | DERIVED   | table1     | index | NULL         | group_idx| 272     | NULL       | 82358731 | Using where; Using index |
+---+-----------+------------+------+---------------+----------+---------+------------+----------+--------------------------+
```

Is there a way to speed this query up?  as it is to be used as part of search facility on a web page ad a minute for the page to load is a bit much.

Thanks in advanced - 
James

```
Table 1
+-----------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                 | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                    | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| billing_date          | date        | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| unique_id             | char(10)    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| imsi                  | bigint(15)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| tim_state             | char(2)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| customer_profile_name | varchar(25) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| serving_opco          | char(5)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| session_start         | datetime    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| session_end           | datetime    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| bytes_input           | int(10)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| bytes_output          | int(10)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| total_in_kibs         | int(10)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

Indxes for table 1
     --+------------+------------------+--------------+--------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table        | Non_unique | Key_name         | Seq_in_index | Column_name  | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+--------------+------------+------------------+--------------+--------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| transactions |          0 | PRIMARY          |            1 | id           | A         |    91714401 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| transactions |          1 | billing_date_idx |            1 | billing_date | A         |          18 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
+--------------+------------+------------------+--------------+--------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+


Table 2
+----------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                   | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| System               | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| Customer             | varchar(50) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Sitecode             | varchar(50) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Name                 | varchar(50) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Serialnumber         | varchar(10) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Operator             | varchar(50) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Sign_Serialnumber    | varchar(10) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| imsi                 | bigint(15)  | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| dtInstalledDateGMT   | datetime    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| dtUninstalledDateGMT | datetime    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+----------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
Indexes for table 2

+-------+------------+----------+--------------+--------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table | Non_unique | Key_name | Seq_in_index | Column_name  | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+-------+------------+----------+--------------+--------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| signs |          0 | PRIMARY  |            1 | id           | A         |        4172 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| signs |          1 | imsi     |            1 | imsi         | A         |        4172 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| signs |          1 | sign_idx |            1 | imsi         | A         |        4172 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| signs |          1 | sign_idx |            2 | Name         | A         |        4172 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| signs |          1 | sign_idx |            3 | System       | A         |        4172 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| signs |          1 | sign_idx |            4 | Customer     | A         |        4172 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| signs |          1 | sign_idx |            5 | Sitecode     | A         |        4172 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| signs |          1 | sign_idx |            6 | Serialnumber | A         |        4172 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
+-------+------------+----------+--------------+--------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+


Explain for billing_date index query 
+------+-------------+-------+------+------------------+----------+---------+---------------------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
| id   | select_type | table | type | possible_keys    | key      | key_len | ref                 | rows     | Extra                                        |
+------+-------------+-------+------+------------------+----------+---------+---------------------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | x     | ALL  | billing_date_idx | NULL     | NULL    | NULL                | 91714401 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | y     | ref  | imsi,sign_idx    | sign_idx | 9       | vodafonegdsp.x.imsi |        1 | Using index                                  |
+------+-------------+-------+------+------------------+----------+---------+---------------------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Firstly, you're joining on a varchar column which is really inefficient.
`table1` shouldn't have the `imsi` column, instead it should have a `int` that references `table2`'s pk, (you could always get the `imsi` from table 2 if you needed to). That alone will make things faster. How many records are in `table2`? Is it a reasonable amount?

Comment: How many records in the result set (how many records in table1 WHERE month(billing_date) = 5)? Are you running this for all years? Is there no other way to join the tables than with a VARCHAR(255) column? What character set is imsi? Can you shorten imsi?

Comment: Is imsi unique on either table?

Comment: @serakfalcon "joining on varchar is inefficient" - got any data on that?

Comment: @Strawberry are you seriously suggesting that a up-to-255-and-more-with-non-ascii-characters byte comparison is possibly faster than a 4-byte comparison?

Comment: @serakfalcon I'm suggesting nothing. I'm only asking if you could provide/point to documentation in support of your assertion.

Comment: @Strawberry just stop and think about what your question suggests. It doesn't take a genius to realize the memory required to do comparisons on ~255 bytes * 80 million vs. 4 bytes * 80 million, how can the varchar possibly be faster, especially when he's not looking up a single value but scanning the whole table! Since you asked twice,  [here](http://www.fromdual.com/impact-of-column-types-on-mysql-join-performance), and [here (the second result of this link matches OP's use better)](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2008/01/24/enum-fields-vs-varchar-vs-int-joined-table-what-is-faster/)

Comment: @serakfalcon So "really inefficient" = "14% less efficient". OK. Good to know.

Comment: where the varchar was only taking up 8 bytes and with 1/5 the data of the OP...

Comment: Serakfalcon - I have changed the imsi column to BIGINT from varchar (coverting to int wasn't big enough to contain the number), there are 4000 records in table2.

Comment: Thanks for all your reponses - Serakfalcon - I have changed the imsi column to BIGINT from varchar (coverting to int wasn't big enough to contain the number), there are 4000 records in table2. - it still takes over 50 seconds. imsi is unique on table2, not on table1 as this is raw logs. I have used month 5 as an example but could change depending on the webpage selection. There is currently only data from 2014 in the table (obviously this will change next year). The result set from month 5 contains 3794 records

Answer (score 0):

If imsi is unique on the tables (suspect it is when combined with the billing date on table 1, and possibly unique on the other table anyway) then you might be able to eliminate the sub query:-

```
SELECT x.imsi,
        y.name, 
        y.Customer, 
        y.System, 
        y.Serialnumber, 
        (SUM(x.bytes_input) / 1048576) AS 'In (Mb)', 
        (SUM(x.bytes_output) / 1048576) AS 'Out (Mb)', 
        (SUM(x.total_in_kibs) / 1024) AS 'Total (Mb)' 
FROM table1 AS x 
INNER JOIN table2 AS y 
ON y.imsi = x.imsi 
WHERE month(x.billing_date) = 5 
GROUP BY x.imsi
```

As an aside, an index on table 1 of group_idx, which includes imsi, billing_date, total_in _kibs, bytes_input, bytes_output seems excessive. I would doubt that the various totals are useful on the end of that index and just narrowing things down with imsi / billing date would be pretty much as effective.

EDIT

I am struggling to see a way to force this to use useful indexes. The following might do, but far from certain.

Try the following, but have an index on billing_date (just billing date):-

```
SELECT y.imsi,
        y.name, 
        y.Customer, 
        y.System, 
        y.Serialnumber, 
        (SUM(x.bytes_input) / 1048576) AS 'In (Mb)', 
        (SUM(x.bytes_output) / 1048576) AS 'Out (Mb)', 
        (SUM(x.total_in_kibs) / 1024) AS 'Total (Mb)' 
FROM table1 AS x 
INNER JOIN table2 AS y 
ON y.imsi = x.imsi 
AND x.billing_date BETWEEN '2014/05/01' AND '2014/05/31'
GROUP BY y.imsi,
        y.name, 
        y.Customer, 
        y.System, 
        y.Serialnumber
```

This should then use that index to return the sub set of rows from table1 that are for May. If you then have an index on table2 on imsi (either as the first column in a covering index, or the only column in an index) that should be used for the join.

Using MONTH(billing_date) = 5 will not use an index as it has to perform the MONTH function on the row before checking the result (82 million times). Checking the date range should use the index on billing date.

Comment: on removing the subquery and using join as above the query now takes 75 seconds instead of 52seconds

Comment: Do you have an index on billing date? If so and you are only interested in month 5 in a particular month change the WHERE to `WHERE x.billing_date BETWEEN '2014/05/01' AND '2014/05/31'` .  How many rows in total is this query bringing back.

Comment: using the between dates brings back the same 3794 records as using the Month(billing_date). However, when I set up the index on billing _date the query does not use it and creates a temporary table and filesort

Comment: Using the dates should enable it to use an index, while using Month(billing_date) should bring back the same result but cannot use an index. Can you post you full table declares (including all the indexes, etc) please. Also the explain with the query checking the range of billing dates.

Comment: Looking at that, it is ignoring the index on billing_date. The cardinality is only 18 which is very low, and possibly suggests that it is ignoring the index as almost all records fall into the date range (which will probably change as more records are added). I have a feeling that the problem is just the large amount of data you now have (~92 million rows). It might be worth trying an index covering both imsi and billing date on table1. With this it might try using table2 and joining table1 to it rather than the other way round (how many imsi values are on table1 but not on table2?)